# Font Face Gotham is not working on my IE 8,9,10 but works fine in my friend's IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, font-face

I have fonts GothamBold, GothamBook and GothamThin. I set font-faces with that fonts in CSS as below:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'GothamBold';
    src: url("../../fonts/GothamBold.eot"); /* IE9 Compatibility Modes */
    src: url("../../fonts/GothamBold.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url("../../fonts/GothamBold.woff") format("woff"), 
         url("../../fonts/GothamBold.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("../../fonts/GothamBold.svg#GothamBold") format("svg");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'GothamBook';
    src: url("../../fonts/GothamBook.eot"), /* IE9 Compatibility Modes */
         url("../../fonts/GothamBook.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url("../../fonts/GothamBook.woff") format("woff"), 
         url("../../fonts/GothamBook.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("../../fonts/GothamBook.otf") format('opentype'),
         url("../../fonts/GothamBook.svg#GothamBook") format("svg");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'GothamThin';
    src: url("../../fonts/GothamThin.eot"), /* IE9 Compatibility Modes */
         url("../../fonts/GothamThin.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url("../../fonts/GothamThin.woff") format("woff"), 
         url('../../fonts/GothamThin.ttf'); /* Safari, Android, iOS */
}
```

but it doesn't works on IE even though it is working on Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Any idea?

I have tried using Montserrat font face kit that I got from fontsquirrel, but still cannot load it on IE.

I have checked my MIME Types in IIS, each extensions has the following type:
.eot - application/vnd.ms-fontobject
.woff - font/x-woff
.ttf - application/octet-stream
.svg - image/svg+xml

It still not working on my IE 8,9,10. BUT it works on my friend's IE??? how that could be???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out that this is because of internet option security settings :| - simply go to internet option > security > custom level > find font download > choose enable. Refresh your page and tadaaa~..yeah, it works.